# Why can't I put ']' after the format specifier when printing 27th escape sequence?

Tags: c

While I was studying the C language, I was printing ASCII codes corresponding to 0 to 255.
However, while printing, an error occurred that the output stopped at 27, and after many attempts, I was able to solve it by putting a space after the character output format specifier.
I became curious and ran printf("%c]",27); the part where the problem occurred.
As a result of executing the code separately, it was found that the result of deleting a certain amount of the output strings came out. (When a character other than ']' was inserted, it worked normally!)
I'm not sure why you get these results. Are there any resources I can refer to on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("%c]",27);
    printf("\n");

    for (; i < 256; i++)
    {
        printf("Teeest [ %d ] = [ %c ]",i,i);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The above code is the code I wrote. The output of this is:

```
 ]
Teeest [ 8 ] = [ ]
Teeest [ 9 ] = [         ]
Teeest [ 10 ] = [
 ]
Teeest [ 11 ] = [  ]
Teeest [ 12 ] = [  ]
 ]eest [ 13 ] = [
Teeest [ 14 ] = [  ]
...
Teeest [ 253 ] = [ ?]
Teeest [ 254 ] = [ ?]
Teeest [ 255 ] = [  ]
```

Comment: 27 is ESC, in combination with other characters it does various things to a console: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

Comment: Google _"ansi escape sequences"_

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will study by referring to the information!

Comment: nachen, "the output stopped at 27" --> Try re-directing output to a file as in `executable_name > a.bin` and then dump `a.bin` to see the real output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal gives that sequence a special meaning. Search for ANSI escape sequences or visit the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Characters 0x00..0x1F and 0x7F are control characters in the ASCII character set, and aren't meant to be displayed. This also applies to UTF-8, which is based on ASCII.

You'll also have problems printing bytes 0x80..0xFF to a UTF-8 terminal as these are only found in multi-byte sequences in UTF-8.